# I want to print the actual gio launch command (e.g.)$ echo " gio launch /usr/share/applications/abiword.desktop" would print: $ Exec=abiword

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am aware that I could just use something like :

```shell
grep Exec= /usr/share/applications/abiword.desktop
```

I could also do something like:

```shell
abiword=$(grep Exec= /usr/share/applications /abiword.desktop)
```

and then:

```shell
echo "$abiword"
```

I would just like to do the same, but use the `gio launch` text.

I am currnetly using both the `$abiword` and the `gio launch` text in a script, and would like to tidy up the script abit. The `gio launch` text will invoke some applications where the `$abiword` will not. I then append the `gio launch` text with various parameters to invoke differnt aspects of an application.

I have tried, as example:

```shell
echo `gio launch /usr/share/applications/abiword.desktop` 
echo '`gio launch /usr/share/applications/abiword.desktop`' 
echo "`gio launch /usr/share/applications/abiword.desktop`"
```

I know it is possible, as I stumbled across the magic incantation 1x, but, a slip of the cat paw and it was gone.

Ideally, then to convert it into a variable for use in my script.

Comment: "I then append the "gio launch" text with various parameters to invoke differnt aspects of an application." ... Why not just add tbose paramaters to `gio launch ...` directly? `gio launch /usr/share/applications/abiword.desktop file-name --option --whatever`

Comment: What is the question?